# Email List Display

Tags: android

i am trying to display emails from gmail in android using ***javamail api*** in a list but i am not able to print ***Message Type*** . how to display message type in for loop...

```
            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            MimeMultipart multipart;     
            BodyPart bodyPart = null;
            String disposition = null;

    //Return result to array of message
            Message[] result = inbox.getMessages(); 

            for(int mail_num = 0; mail_num < result.length; mail_num++)
            {                         
              multipart = (MimeMultipart) result[mail_num].getContent();     
              bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(mail_num);

              String from = InternetAddress.toString(result[mail_num].getFrom());                            

              t1.setText(result[m`enter code here`ail_num].getSubject());
              t2.setText(bodyPart.getContent().toString());
              t3.setText(result[mail_num].getSentDate().toGMTString());
              t4.setText(from.toString());                    
            }
```

Comment: Please Help me out....if anybody has idea about it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe following code can help you :)

```
  public static void receiveEmail(String pop3Host, String storeType,  
  String user, String password) {  
  try {  
   //1) get the session object  
   Properties properties = new Properties();  
   properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);  
   Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

   //2) create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server  
   POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) emailSession.getStore(storeType);  
   emailStore.connect(user, password);  

   //3) create the folder object and open it  
   Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");  
   emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);  

   //4) retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it  
   Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();  
   for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {  
    Message message = messages[i];  
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");  
    System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));  
    System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());  
    System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);  
    System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());  
   }  

   //5) close the store and folder objects  
   emailFolder.close(false);  
   emailStore.close();  

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
  catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
  catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  String host = "mail.javatpoint.com";//change accordingly  
  String mailStoreType = "pop3";  
  String username= "sonoojaiswal@javatpoint.com";  
  String password= "xxxxx";//change accordingly  

  receiveEmail(host, mailStoreType, username, password);  

 }  
}
```