# How to get gmail mails subject in android?

Tags: android, email, gmail

I want to control e-mails subjects of spesific people who send mail me. I found some code about it but i don't know how i control subjects of e-mails. Is there anyone to know how can i achieve this? Thanks. Here is the code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
//IMAPS protocol
props.setProperty(“mail.store.protocol”, “imaps”);
//Set host address
props.setProperty(“mail.imaps.host”, imaps.gmail.com);
//Set specified port
props.setProperty(“mail.imaps.port”, “993″);
//Using SSL
props.setProperty(“mail.imaps.socketFactory.class”, “javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory”);
props.setProperty(“mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback”, “false”);
//Setting IMAP session
Session imapSession = Session.getInstance(props);

Store store = imapSession.getStore(“imaps”);
//Connect to server by sending username and password.
//Example mailServer = imap.gmail.com, username = abc, password = abc
store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
//Get all mails in Inbox Forlder
inbox = store.getFolder(“Inbox”);
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
//Return result to array of message
Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [did not was looking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26154893/2413972) a friend. You need next:

```
System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
```